# How to dispatch an ad-hoc query, with Relay?

Tags: relayjs

I'm new to Relay, still trying to wrap my head around it. Based on my understanding, Relay ties queries to components. This way, you can say that a component needs to be provided x, y and z from the GraphQL server. Based on my understanding, the official `react-relay` library will dispatch those queries at the appropriate time, likely when the component is about to be rendered.

This all makes sense to me for straight forward use cases, such as simply displaying a list of data.

What I'm confused on how to do, though, is how to dispatch a query that may not quite fall into the category of something that would be tied to a component. A query such as one that attempts to fetch a user authentication session token, or something. This is my current situation: I'm trying to create a user sign in form that fetches a session token from GraphQL. I've got a parameterized GraphQL field that requires username and password arguments and will return a session token if they're valid. I just can't figure out how to use Relay to query for that session token.

I'd essentially just need to dispatch a query, and handle the response (place that session token into the React application state).

Any ideas?

Comment: I found this after asking a similar qn https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34346273/search-functionality-using-relay Its disappointing to see no response to your qn. cc @steveluscher

Comment: After running into a lot of questions and issues without clear answers, I decided to just drop GraphQL and Relay for now. I've gone back to Redux and just a typical HTTP RESTful API. I see a lot of good stuff with GraphQL and Relay, but too many questions relating to stuff like ad hoc queries (or how to do that kind of work flow with Relay) and also user authorization type stuff, like which fields should be visible to who. It started to require way too much server and client side code to handle showing certain certain fields to users with permission. I really liked everything else, though.

Comment: thanks you for the response.

Comment: Should considering renaming this for better SEO. This is a hidden gem of the internet.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Relay's APIs are primarily focused on making it easy to fetch data for components, but Relay also supports ad-hoc queries. The API is relatively low-level, with distinct functions for fetching and reading data. Here's an example of how to fetch an ad-hoc query and access the response:

```js
// Create a query with values for any variables:
var query = Relay.createQuery(Relay.QL`query ... `, {var: 'value'});
// Fetch any fields that have not yet been cached:
Relay.Store.primeCache({query}, readyState => {
  if (readyState.done) {
    // When all data is ready, read the data from the cache:
    var data = Relay.Store.readQuery(query)[0];
    /* access fields on `data` */
  }
});
```

If the data doesn't need to be synchronized with Relay's cache, you can also use a plain network request (XHR, fetch, etc) to send a plain string query to your GraphQL endpoint.

Comment: When you want to be sure to get the latest data from your server, you could also use Relay.Store.forceFetch({query}, readyStateCallback)

Answer (score 1):

It's honestly probably easiest to use a separate library.  I use [`Lokka`](https://github.com/kadirahq/lokka) in my `node` projects and it's dead-simple and reliable.

```
// config
const Lokka = require('lokka').Lokka;
const Transport = require('lokka-transport-http').Transport;

const client = new Lokka({
  transport: new Transport('http://graphql-swapi.parseapp.com/')
});



// query
client.query(`
  {
    allFilms {
      films {
        ...${filmInfo}
      }
    }
  }
`).then(result => {
  console.log(result.allFilms.films);
});
```