# search functionality using relay

Tags: relayjs

How to implement a search functionality with relay?

So, the workflow is

- user navigate to `search form`.

there should not be any query (as in relay container) when initializing the view.

- user fills the field values, and press the action/search button.

a relay query is sent to the server

- results are received from the server.

page displays it and  relay reconciles the `filtered` results with local cache.

I have not seen an example of ad hoc query but only part of a relay container (which it resolves before component initialization). So, how to model it. should it be like a mutation?

Comment: Is something stopping you from just using arguments & variables on a connection ? So every time you want to search, update the initial variables and relay will query the filtered results.

Comment: nothing stopping me to do this way, but I thought it will send an initial request when the container initialized. I was thinking more of sending a request only when user initiate action. Will try your suggestion and get back with you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If I understand correctly you'd like to not send any query at all for the component until the user enters some search text, at which point the query should sent. This can be accomplished with the example posted by @Xuorig, with one addition: use GraphQL's `@include` directive to skip the fragment until a variable is set. Here's the extended example:

```
export default Relay.createContainer(Search, {
  initialVariables: {
    count: 3,
    query: null,
    hasQuery: false, // `@include(if: ...)` takes a boolean
  },
  fragments: {
    viewer: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Viewer {
        # add `@include` to skip the fragment unless $query/$hasQuery are set
        items(first: $count, query: $query) @include(if: $hasQuery) {
          edges {
            node {
              ...
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `,
  },
});
```

This query will be skipped initially since the include condition is falsy. Then, the component can call `setVariables({query: someQueryText, hasQuery: true})` when text input is changed, at which point the `@include` condition will become true and the query will be sent to the server.

Comment: hi @joe-savona, may be the API changed recently but I cannot use string with `if`, which gives error `Argument "if" expected type "Boolean!" but got: "sdsd". irst:9) @include(if:"sdsd")`. Tried like `search(query: $query, first: $first) @include(if: !!$query)` but that too errored out `Unexpected !`. so, I ended up using another boolean flag to indicate whether `$query` is empty or not. Is there a way I could avoid the extra variable?

Comment: Good point - `@include(if: ...)` only accepts booleans, so you'd need another variable if `$query` is a string. I'll update the answer.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. It fails and throws the `fetchWithRetries(): Still no successful response after 1 retries, giving up.` error. It works fine when `hasQuery` is *initially* set to `true`.

Answer (score 2):

This is the way I've implemented simple search in my project:

```
export default Relay.createContainer(Search, {
  initialVariables: {
    count: 3,
    title: null,
    category: null,
  },
  fragments: {
    viewer: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Viewer {
        items(first: $count, title: $title, category: $category) {
          edges {
            node {
              ...
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `,
  },
});
```

Your search form simply has to update the initialVariables using `this.props.relay.setVariables` and relay will query the new data.

Comment: thanks. but wouldn't it send an initial request when the container is initialized.  I will try it out. thanks again.

Comment: Oh. Yes it would send an initial request that would return all results. As a work around, you could dynamically append a container that would have the query I posted in the answer when the user searched and show something else when there was no search.