# forceFetch a specific fragment from a Relay container

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relayjs, relay

If a container has multiple fragments, how can I `forceFetch` only one of them ?

```js
Relay.createContainer(MyContainerComponent, {
    fragments: {
        fragment1: () => Relay.QL`my first fragment`,
        fragment2: () => Relay.QL`my second fragment`
    } 
});
```

According to the docs, calling `this.props.relay.forceFetch()` will update every fragments associated to the container.

While force fetching 'as is' does the job, the whole point of Relay is to avoid over/under fetching.

Any advice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refetches are managed by the container, so one solution would be:

```
Relay.createContainer(MyContainerComponent, {
    fragments: {
        fragment1: () => Relay.QL`fragment on SomeThing { ${SomeThingContainer.getFragment("something")}`,
        fragment2: () => Relay.QL`fragment on OtherThing { ${OtherThingContainer.getFragment("otherthing")}`
    } 
});
```

Then just use the two sub containers to refetch their individual fragments.

If you actually need data from both fragments in `MyContainerComponent` so you can't separate those into sub-containers, refetching the full container fragment makes sense for me...

However, if you *really* need data from both fragments and you *really* only want to refetch one of them, you can always use the imperative Store API to execute an ad-hoc query for whatever you want. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34053662/how-to-dispatch-an-ad-hoc-query-with-relay) for details on that.

ASIDE:

> the whole point of Relay is to avoid over/under fetching

I disagree... That's a welcome benefit of course, but the real "point" is to be a declarative framework for getting data to your components. There is no simple, declarative API for refetching individual container fragments, true. Maybe there should be! But I think it's probably more likely that you are prematurely optimizing here :)

Comment: Thanks NevilleS, I'm definitely micro optimizing here, but sill, it's good to know that Relay isn't gonna get in my way if I really need to do that sort of things.